# How to hydrate objects?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've started looking at a small Angular problem, and while I've been scouring tutorials and docs I've not managed to find a good way of solving this. I could solve it outside of Angular fairly easily, but I'm hoping someone might be able to give me a slight nudge down the Angular route for it?

Essentially I've got 2 objects pulled from different source files:

**Foos**

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: "Foo1",
   bars: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
}
```

**Bars**

```
 {
    id: 1,
    name: "Bar1"
 }
```

I'm trying to display a list of each on a separate page. But I need to list the names of the `Bars` in the `Foos.html` page and the names of linked `Foos` on the `Bars.html` page.

I guess there are two possible solutions to this:

- Lookup in the UI
- Hydrate within a Service

My Foo type looks like:

```
{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    bars: Bar[];
}
```

In a non Angular world, I believe the right way to do this would be within the Service (or more likely via some sort of controller). I've been trying to implement this at the service level, but I'm struggling to work out how I might do it with it being across 2 requests? Especially considering typically the Angular `HttpClient` automatically converts to the strong type of `Foo`.

Am I using the wrong approach here? I can't see any mention of `Controllers` within Angular2+ so am I missing something here?

Comment: A state management library such as ngrx or ngxs would be a good solution to this problem. If you are talking about separate pages, another way of dealing with this would be a resolver. You could utilize a service in this resolver, this service would call the http requests only if the data hasn't been requested already, and otherwise consume the already available data(this logic you will have to write yourself inside the service, you would save the response in the service making it available for every next service method call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your instinct about this not being an "angular" problem is correct. These days, I'd say this is more of an RxJS problem. You need to make two requests, and put the data from the second payload, into the first one, and then return that combined payload.

In RxJS parlance that boils down to something like this:

```
import { HttpClient } ...

const stream_1$ = this.http.get ( 'url_1' );
const stream_2$ = this.http.get ( 'url_2' );

stream_1$.pipe ( 
    switchMap ( x => { 
       // x will be the result of the first stream, 
       // you are literally switching to the second stream
       return stream_2$.pipe ( 
          map ( y => { 
            // y will be the result of the second stream. 
            // So you want to combine x, and y. 
            // Do your hydration here
            return ( { some transformed object using x + y data } );
          } )
    } )
).subscribe ( x => // result will be that combined object )
```

That's how you go about this sort of thing these days, a pretty standard RxJS pattern. You may want to look into different operators, mergeMap and so on, but the general gist is what I put above.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that looks like a great pointer in the right direction which is all I was after :) Some of the tutorial examples are just a little bit too "perfect world" to know how to apply!

Comment: Haha I know that feeling. "I have two http calls and want to combine them into a final result...that's it." Tutorial: Ok so first we'll install these libraries and then set up our Effects and Actions and Reducers and then set up the tests for them and then create the initial AppState and then write this query using this new NGRX API and then...PLEASE STOP where's the HELLO WORLD version!!!